# PHP (Yii) Passing variable to controlle via form

Tags: php, yii

I have a variable in my view `$models` which I want to pass to my controller for a function which I'm calling using a submit button.

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('', 'post');?>
    <fieldset>
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Confirm', array('name'=>'confirm', 'class'=>'btn btn-danger')); ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

how do I access the `$models` variable from the function in the controller.

I'm not entirely sure how this works and I would have thought I could just use `$_POST['models']` but it's saying it's an undefined variable (although I can var_dump on the page and it's definitely not) so I think i'm just trying to access it incorrectly or not submitting it correctly.

Comment: I also tried passing it as a hidden variable but it says "array to string conversion" in response to `<input type="hidden" name="models" value="<?php echo $models?>" />` does value have to be a string? I want to pass an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a html form submission and php syntax problem, but not yii-specific.

Whatever framework you use, even in plain static html, the basic idea of form submission is the same: if you want to send data to a page with a form, you need to put that data in your form, either as a form input the end-user can enter or select (text inputs, dragdown boxes, radios and checkboxes), or as a hidden input. Page2 doesn't care if $models was set on Page1. You need to send the data to Page2.

In PHP, you can't display an array with echo $arrayVar.

For your specific problem, I assume $models is an array of models. Do NOT pass the whole models' definition in your form, just pass their primary key ids. On your next action, just fetch back those models with YourMode::model()->findByPk(). I think you could do this two ways:

```
<?php
// Idea 1 (untested code)
// Convert an array of ids to a string
$tmp = array();
foreach($models as $model){
    $tmp[] = $model->yourPrimaryKey;
}
echo '<input type="hidden" name="whateveryourparamis" value="'.CHtml::encode( implode('|',$tmp)).'">';

// $whateveryourparamis will be a string like: "47|388|638|877". Use explode() to convert it to an array
// Your could also use json_encode/json_decode instead of implode/explode


// Idea 2 (untested code)
// Pass an array of ids (yeah, this is possible)
foreach($models as $model){
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="whateveryourparamis[]" value="'.CHtml::encode($model->yourPrimaryKey).'">';
}

// $whateveryourparamis will be an array like: array(47, 388, 638, 877)
?>
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, this is very appreciated. I'll sort it out tonight :)

Answer (score -2):

I suppose this ain't the best way to achieve what you want, but you can always access the controller through:

```
$controller = Yii::app()->controller;
```

And then do with it whatever you want, for storing a variable in your controller, you probably will have to add a variable to your class.

Another variant would be to use CStatePersister http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CStatePersister or you could also directly write in to $_SESSION..

From what you write, I suppose you should use Sessions for storing that data.